# Tidymodels class cost

Tags: r, tidymodels, imbalanced-data

I am dealing with a prediction case where the data is suffering from a strong imbalance in the binary prediction target. Is there a way of penalizing wrong predictions of the minority class with a cost matrix in TidyModels? I know that caret had this implemented, but the information I find in TidyModels is quite confusing.
All I find is the `baguette::class_cost()` function from the experimental baguette package, which only seems to apply to bagged trees models.

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66759453/tidymodels-classify-as-true-only-if-the-probability-is-75-or-higher) or better the [probably package](https://probably.tidymodels.org/) can help you to post-process your model results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to set a `classification_cost()`:

```r
library(yardstick)
#> For binary classification, the first factor level is assumed to be the event.
#> Use the argument `event_level = "second"` to alter this as needed.
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
```

```r
# Two class example
data(two_class_example)

# Assuming `Class1` is our "event", this penalizes false positives heavily
costs1 <- tribble(
  ~truth,   ~estimate, ~cost,
  "Class1", "Class2",  1,
  "Class2", "Class1",  2
)

# Assuming `Class1` is our "event", this penalizes false negatives heavily
costs2 <- tribble(
  ~truth,   ~estimate, ~cost,
  "Class1", "Class2",  2,
  "Class2", "Class1",  1
)

classification_cost(two_class_example, truth, Class1, costs = costs1)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric             .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>               <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 classification_cost binary         0.288
classification_cost(two_class_example, truth, Class1, costs = costs2)
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   .metric             .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>               <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 classification_cost binary         0.260
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In tidymodels, you can use this metric either just to compute results after the fact or in tuning. Learn [more here](https://www.tmwr.org/performance.html).

Comment: Thank you for showing me this, I somehow did not find this on my own. If I may pose a follow-up question: How would I go about using this metric for tuning? simply use the `classification_cost` function with its cost matrix for the `metrics` argument in `tune_grid()`? 
So far I have not used functions with arguments for the `metrics`-argument.

Comment: You create a `metric_set()` and then use that in a tuning function. I have a couple of blog posts that demonstrate this, [such as this one](https://juliasilge.com/blog/baseball-racing/).